# In Python 3, how can I extract a list of number from a file at a specific URL?

Tags: python, string, methods, python-3.x, numbers

The URL is: http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat

This is what i need to achieve:

```
'''(str) -> reader
Open the URL url, read past the three-line header, and 
return the open reader.'''
```

This is what i tried:

```
list1=[]

f=urllib.request.urlopen('http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat')

data=f.read()

datasplit=data.split()

for x in datasplit:
    if x.isdigit():
        list1.append(datasplit)

print (list1)
```

And it's still not showing what I want. What I want is to get all of the numbers in a `list` called `list1` so that i can do further operations.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: No he doesn't. In Python 3, he wants [`urllib.request.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen), exactly as he has. And even in Python 2, you don't want to use [`urllib.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen), which has been deprecated since 2.6.

Comment: Woops. My apologies. I zoned out on the OP.

Comment: Do you really want to read this 2D array into a flat list like this?

Comment: @abarnert There isn't really a lot of useful metadata in preserving the original structure of the data - it's still a sequential list, by month. If that's all you need, why bother?

Comment: @selllikesybok: In the original structure, each row is a year, and each column is a month. You don't think that's meaningful information?

Comment: @abarnert That depends on what he is doing with it, really. The file itself does not provide enough detail to (easily) programmatically assign specific month/year values. So only their relative position matters. Enough information about relative position persists in a flat list to reconstruct the original, if need be.

Comment: @selllikesybok: Sure it does. The first column in January, the first row is 1964.

Comment: @abarnert You know this from reading the page. How would you (simply) tell your parser to collect this information and apply it? :) The point is - yes, you can preserve the structure, if it matters for your purposes to do so. If it does not, there is no great need, as you can reconstruct it later without significant difficulty.

Comment: @selllikesybok: Interpreting the first row as 1964 would require more complicated parsing, so I wouldn't do that part if it wasn't necessary. But treating the 2D structure as a 2D structure doesn't make things more complicated at all, and it makes the code clearer, and interpreting the first column in a row of 12 months as January is obvious, so I don't see any reason to go out of your way to avoid getting that information.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit` returns `False` for all items in `datasplit` except '1964', because the numbers are `float` values (containing a `.`), not `int`. `isdigit` only checks for numbers.

Also, you probably don't want to add the whole `datasplit` list to your result, only the actual item.

You could skip the first two lines (using `readline`) before splitting it, and just convert the items in the result to `float`:

```
f=urllib.request.urlopen('http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat')
f.readline()
f.readline()
list1 = [float(v) for v in f.read().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, you are looking to see if, for any element in the list `datasplit`, that element is composed of nothing but digits. If that is the case, then you are appending the entirety of `datasplit` into `list1`. The only element which is all digits is '1964', so you get one copy of the whole list appended, and that's it.

What you should do, in this case, is the following:

```
list1=[]

f=urllib.request.urlopen('http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat')

data=f.read()

datasplit=data.split()

for x in datasplit:
    if '.' in x:
        list1.append(x)

print (list1)
```

What this does is to see if there is a '.' in the current element of `datasplit` (since you only want the data, and all of the data contains one '.' character, and nothing else does). Then, if the `if` condition evaluates to `True`, it appends only the current element to `list1`, which is what you wanted.

Keep in mind, at the end, you are still left with a list of strings - to process them as numbers you'll have to convert them later.

**EDITED TO ADD:**

If you want `list1` to actually have numerical objects instead of strings, the simplest change to my answer is to alter the append statement:

```
list1.append(float(x))
```

Which will cast the value of `x` to a `float`, so you can perform numerical operations on the contents of `list1` now.

**EDITED AGAIN TO ADD:**

Jsut for fun, if you are a big fan of one-liners, you could do it as:

`list1=[e for e in urllib.request.urlopen('http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat').read().split() if '.' in e]`

But this makes error handling difficult, at best. I would not recommend including I/O inside of a list comprehension, as a general rule.

Comment: The `urllib` package doesn't have a request method (or function); it has a `request` module, which has a [`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) function.

Comment: Also, checking for valid floats by `'.' in` is highly specific, and odd enough to potentially confuse any reader who isn't looking directly at the file while reading the code.

Comment: Yeah, missed the Py3 bit, editted. Also, he isn't looking for floats, he is looking to collect a set of tokens from text which all match a certain set of criteria. `re` would be overkill here, of course. He wants to parse a page, not write a generalized parser.

Comment: "what i want is to get all the numbers in a list called list1". So yes, he is looking for floats.

Comment: He wants the data - he called it 'numbers', but in fact they are not numbers, they are strings. The strings he is looking for here happen to be string representations of floats with a precision of 1. So, the correct approach is to use string manipulation to get them, then convert into the correct object for whatever later processing steps are involved.

Comment: He called it "numbers" because that's what he's looking for. It would be more accurate to say "string representations of numbers" or "numerals" or something similar, but really, his rule for what counts is not a rule about strings, it's "represents a float".

Answer (score 0):

In general, if there's a simple way to describe the format, it's clearer to parse in terms of that format than to ignore it and try to recover the information in some other way. And the format here is trivial: It's got 3 header lines that you want to ignore, and then it's got a table as whitespace-separated CSV (or, if you prefer, fixed-width columns).

If you use that format, the numbers are "all the columns in all the rows of the table". If you ignore the format, you have to rely on the fact that all of the values in the columns happen to have some particular structure that nothing else on the page does, which is a lot easier to get wrong (as you did), and much harder to understand for anyone reading your code who isn't looking directly at the file as he does so.

So, how do you parse a whitespace-separated table? Either with the `csv` module, or read line by line and `split` each line. I'll show both ways:

```
f=urllib.request.urlopen('http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat')
for header in range(3):
    next(f)
list1 = [float(column) for row in f for column in row.split()]

f=urllib.request.urlopen('http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat')
for header in range(3):
    next(f)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
list1 = [float(column) for row in reader for column in row]
```